# Set maxzoom in mapcache, but get error when I restart apache server

Tags: wms, mapserver, tilecache, mapcache, geocaching

I have a problem with mapcache, I want to set maxzoom level = 21, but I get error when i try to restart apache server.

[image]

Here's error I get :

[image]

Comment: How many zoom level do you have in WMS ?

Comment: I use mapserver for WMS. It's work well when I access WMS with zoom over 21. how i can set ?

Comment: Can you try with low zoom level like 10 ?

Comment: yes, it's work well if i set 10, and I was try to set another zoom level. I got this :  if I set max zoom below 17 it will error.

Comment: May be your max resolution is 17 level

Comment: Please provide all code and error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Comment: in mapcache can't get wms in zoom more than 17 level, I need to get wms data with max zoom level 21. :( even though without (mapcache), I mean (wms + leaflet) I can get max zoom level 21 and rendered very well.

Comment: @NurulHidayat Did you try to include all resolutions in mapcache xml file ?

Comment: yes, how should that problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the resolutions for zoom levels:

Example (You need to define yours):

```
<resolutions>0.703125000000000 0.351562500000000 0.175781250000000 8.78906250000000e-2 4.39453125000000e-2 2.19726562500000e-2 1.09863281250000e-2 5.49316406250000e-3 2.74658203125000e-3 1.37329101562500e-3 6.86645507812500e-4 3.43322753906250e-4 1.71661376953125e-4 8.58306884765625e-5 4.29153442382812e-5 2.14576721191406e-5 1.07288360595703e-5 5.36441802978516e-6</resolutions>
```

http://mapserver.org/mapcache/config.html#grid

Comment: stil get error when I set maxzoom with number above 17.

Comment: Same error or different ?

Comment: the different is here : invalid grid maxzoom/minzoom 0/19

Comment: I was try, and my code is like this. but stil get same error when i restart apache server.

Comment: `<grid name="jimatt">
    <srs>epsg:4326</srs>
     <size>256 256</size>
     <extent>-180 -90 180 90</extent>
     <units>m</units>
     <resolutions>0.703125000000000 0.351562500000000 0.175781250000000 8.78906250000000e-2 4.39453125000000e-2 2.19726562500000e-2 1.09863281250000e-2 5.49316406250000e-3 2.74658203125000e-3 1.37329101562500e-3 6.86645507812500e-4 3.43322753906250e-4 1.71661376953125e-4 8.58306884765625e-5 4.29153442382812e-5 2.14576721191406e-5 1.07288360595703e-5 5.36441802978516e-6</resolutions>
   </grid>`

Comment: resolutions are not 21

Comment: and this `<tileset name="basemap">
       <metadata>
         <title>Jimatt</title>
         <abstract>Jimatt Map</abstract>
      </metadata>
      <source>Jimatt</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid">jimatt</grid>

      <format>PNG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>3600</expires>
   </tileset>`. I can start apache with this, but the map map does not display anything.

Comment: @NurulHidayat the example I've put in my answer is sample and will not work with your data. You need to check the resolutions of your WMS.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it's work for me.

must create own grid and set resolution till zoom number 21.

`<resolutions>156543.0339280410 78271.51696402048 39135.75848201023 19567.87924100512 9783.939620502561 4891.969810251280 2445.984905125640 1222.992452562820 611.4962262814100 305.7481131407048 152.8740565703525 76.43702828517624 38.21851414258813 19.10925707129406 9.554628535647032 4.777314267823516 2.388657133911758 1.194328566955879 0.5971642834779395 0.2985821417389698 0.1492910708694849 0.0746455354347424 0.0373227677173712 </resolutions>`

Comment: That's what I've mentioned in my answer.